# What does "CSSLayerBlockRule" in Chrome Console mean?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I am working on a typical "snake" game in js, and came across the following output on Chrome's console:

[image: console output]

The prints from my script are working fine, but I cannot find any documentation on the last two lines. They do not seem like errors to me, but what are they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an [interface](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-5/#the-csslayerblockrule-interface) used internally by the browser that represents the JS side of [CSS cascade layers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@layer) which so far is only [supported by Chrome, Firefox and Safari](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_at-rules_layer).

Read more about it in this [blog post](https://www.bram.us/2021/09/15/the-future-of-css-cascade-layers-css-at-layer/).

Running your code snippet in Chrome gives me this (expected) output:

[image]

Comment: But why is it displayed in the console?

Comment: Because you have entered it. I'm not aware of any way to get the displayed output other than entering `CSSLayerBlockRule` and **not** pressing Enter. Maybe you have typed `"cssl"` and pressed Tab?

Comment: That's what I thought too, so I added some console prints to see where my code generates that line. Can you point out the line to me that generates that output? I seem to miss something obvious here.
I have not entered anything into the console, and refreshed multiple times to make sure.

Comment: No, you must literally have typed it in, with the console being open and having focus. I just rand your snippet in Chrome, and the console does not have the output you show.

Comment: So when I press "F5" and don't type anything else, it should not display that line, right? But it does.

Comment: Clear the console first by entering `clear()` in the console and pressing Enter.

Comment: F5 doesn't change what has been entered in the console.

Comment: You are correct, it does not show again. Strange is that I have never heard of it before, and have certanly not typed it out myself. Does it make sense to leave that question up, or should I delete it? Not sure if it has any value on SO.

Comment: It might, in the context of my answer, help people understand what that function is for. Since it's a very new thing, more people might search for the `CSSLayerBlockRule` in the near future.